# How add css border at google maps v3 icon

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps-api-3

I want to add css border at google maps icon.

But I don't know, how can I do?

This is my code! plz....!

http://fiddle.jshell.net/yX7ce/9/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 4,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            myOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: map.getCenter(),
          map: map,
          title: 'Click to zoom',
          icon: 'images/a01.jpg'
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          if (map.getZoom() == 8) {
            map.setZoom(4);
          } else {
            map.setZoom(8);
          }
        });
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Comment: Since you're already adding a custom icon, why not just add a border to the icon itself?

Comment: I want to make that the mouse click highlight effect. such as :http://www.geophotoshow.com/flickr/

Answer (score 2):

As you've probably noticed there is no convenient way to add attributes to the icons that would allow you to reach them via css.

The real solution is to create custom overlays that act as icons:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#CustomOverlays

This is fairly intensive.

The easy quick and dirty solution in your case is to use jquery to look for attributes that match your custom icons = 'http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7033/6790615621_504e654272_s.jpg' - and listen for mouseover / mouseout events. This isn't very flexible of course...

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options:

1) Generate two images for all your icons, one without the border and one with and then swap the MarkerIcon when you click

2) As ScottE says, use a CustomOverlay which basically allows you to put HTML at a LatLng point and then you can add click listeners to apply/remove styles to the Overlays.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off making the border be part of your original icon image, because (a) you have now way to know the `img` element's id/class to apply CSS to and (b) even if you could, it'd be a rectangular border, which may not be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Use [MarkerWithLabel for V3](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.8/docs/reference.html) and you can apply styles (and custom labels) to markers. [Their example](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.8/examples/basic.html) shows basic usage with borders.

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->
 <style type="text/css">
   .labels {
     text-align: center;
     width: 40px;     
     border: 2px solid black;
   }
 </style>
```

And the JS

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
 var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47805, -123.84716);

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
   zoom: 12,
   center: latLng,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 });

 var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
   position: latLng,
   draggable: false,
   map: map,
   labelContent: "hello world",
   labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
   labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
   labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#map_canvas").css({border: '1px solid silver'})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But not #map_canvas. I want to add image(icon)

Answer (score -1):

Basically you need to use styled google map. See an [example](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) here